# Impact of Jacoco instrumentation on performance

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

I am planning to use Jacoco for few of our projects to find out the code coverage.

The code coverage is to be obtained for UI Selenium Test.

Whats is the impact on performance when the instrumentation is done?

Edit-> with more info

I am planning to attach the jacoco to JVM and then run Selenium UI tests against the Application under test. One of the concerns that is being raised is that since jacoco uses on the fly instrumentation it could make the application a tad slow.

What will be the impact of instrumentation on the application under tests performance?

Comment: Please tell us more about your question.  As is this is not very clear.

Comment: His question seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: This discussion give you some numbers. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/VgeTQfyslgw

Comment: Why dont you try it and see how much you are getting impacted. I would say if it's acceptable, then go for it. I don't think personally that jacoco will impact the performance significantly.